# Sharing observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have two delivery-type forms (with name, address, postcode etc), and a button saying 'Delivery address is the same as Shipping Address'. Basically i'm trying to make it so that when a user clicks that button, the same observables from the first field are then shared with the second field. How i have approached this (probably very wrongly) is by setting two sets of observables like so:

```
    self.firstName = ko.observable("");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("");
self.phoneNumber = ko.observable("");
self.address1 = ko.observable("");
self.address2 = ko.observable("");
self.city = ko.observable("");
self.state = ko.observable("");
self.postcode = ko.observable("");

    self.delFirstName = ko.observable("");
    self.delLastName = ko.observable("");
self.delPhoneNumber = ko.observable("");
self.delAddress1 = ko.observable("");
self.delAddress2 = ko.observable("");
self.delCity = ko.observable("");
self.delState = ko.observable("");
self.delPostcode = ko.observable("");
```

And then i tried to set a function, that when clicked, would share the shipping details across.

```
self.sameDelAddress = function() {
    self.delFirstName() = self.firstName(self.firstName);
            self.delLastName() = self.lastName(self.lastName);
    self.delPhoneNumber() = self.phoneNumber(self.phoneNumber);
    self.delAddress1() = self.address1(self.address1);
    self.delAddress2() = ko.observable(self.address2);
    self.delCity() = ko.observable(self.city);
    self.delState() = ko.observable(self.state);
    self.delPostcode() = ko.observable(self.postcode);
}
```

Comment: Sentiment in original version appreciated - but, discouraged in SO questions!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Steven! Please take a look at stackoverflow.com/about to see the format of questions to get the best possible answers! It's a bit hard to see what your question is - is this not working for you? What signs do you have that it's not working? (For example, maybe when you click, the observables are not shared.)

Comment: Sorry only just saw these comments. still getting used to Stack Overflow, great resource! This was not working, and nothing seems to be coming through on the console in Chrome. I may have to have a long read about error handling. Basically the observables were not assigning to their del-prepended counterparts, and not telling me why. It really threw me, but with Dans solution i've started to understand more about how variables are assigned in KO. I'm going to read more into this (and the about section of SO) and if its cool to post a solution when i've finished i'll post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something like the code below.  Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4fG3/12/) fiddle for a working example.

Try updating one field after you have selected the checkbox, you will see that the other field updates automatically.

```
function addressModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable("");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("");
    self.phoneNumber = ko.observable("");
    self.address1 = ko.observable("");
    self.address2 = ko.observable("");
    self.city = ko.observable("");
    self.state = ko.observable("");
    self.postcode = ko.observable("");
}

function deliveryModel(shipAddress, billAddress) {
    var self = this;
    self.shippingAddress = ko.observable(shipAddress);
    self.billingAddress = ko.observable(billAddress);
    self.addressesAreSame = ko.observable();

    self.addressesAreSame.subscribe(function(newValue){
        if(newValue===true){
            self.billingAddress(self.shippingAddress());
        }else{
            self.billingAddress(new addressModel());
        }
    });
}

var delivery = new deliveryModel(new addressModel(), new addressModel());
ko.applyBindings(delivery);
```

Binding example:

```
<div data-bind="with: shippingAddress">
    Shipping Address<br />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: address1" />
</div>
<div data-bind="with: billingAddress">
    Billing Address<br />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: address1" />
</div>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: addressesAreSame" /> Billing same as shipping
```

Comment: @Wojciech I modified my answer to handle selecting and de-selecting the checkbox.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Dan! I shall try this when i get home and let you know the results. 

Once again, thank you for your time, it is much appreciated!